# How can I set primaryContainer color with ColorScheme.fromSwatch() in Material Theme

Tags: flutter, layout, colors, themes

`colorScheme` offers in general the `primaryContainer` parameter. However, when I use `colorScheme.fromSwatch' this is no longer available such as many other parameters.

My understanding of `fromSwatch` is, I create a standard theme based on the key colors that I define within the `color.Scheme`. At least this is what I am aiming to do.

So how can I adapt the `primaryContainer`  without defining every mandatory parameter of a scheme?

Comment: Do you have a custom color scheme?

Comment: not yet. That is why I wanted to create a simple template by just amending the parameters of interest.

Comment: ok cool. I usually have a custom color theme and just make the call theme.of(context).colorScheme.primaryContainer, etc., etc. Interesting question you got here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `copyWith` method.

```dart
ColorScheme.fromSwatch().copyWith(
    primaryContainer: Colors.red,
  ),
```

More about [ColorScheme](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ColorScheme-class.html)